# ASCII Value of string in button title

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have three buttons with all same property other than their title. Titles are 'A', 'B' and 'C' respectively. I wrote a method where I have written all common properties of these three buttons and calling this method where I want to add those buttons on view. I have done all theses, but struct at button Title. I used for loop to add theses buttons to view. 
Here is my code:

This is method with all common properties of three buttons.

```
-(UIButton *)setMiddlePlayButton{
    UIButton * middleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [middleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Middle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [middleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    middleButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    return middleButton;
}
```

Calling the method in this way to add buttons on the view.

```
for(int i= 0; i<3; i++){
        UIButton * middleButtons = [self setMiddlePlayButton];
        middleButtons.tag= 2+i;
        //Here I have to add button Title which is 'A' for first button with tag 2, 'B' for second button with tag 3 and 'C' for third button. 
        [self.view addSubView:middleButtons];

    }
```

I am not finding a way to get the title, is anything possible with ASCII value? Or is there any other way to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
for(int i= 0; i<3; i++){
    UIButton * middleButtons = [self setMiddlePlayButton];
    middleButtons.tag= 2+i;
    [middleButtons setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 65+i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:middleButtons];   
}
```